# Where can I find the envvars configuration file (if there are any) in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

Where can I find the envvars configuration file (if there are any) in CentOS?

I know in Apache2, I can find it from /etc/apache2/envvars

Please advise, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at `/etc/profile`

Answer (score 1):

Global Environment variable file is :- `/etc/profile`

Local Environment Variable ( User Specific ) file is :- `~/.bash_profile`